# "Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError" while installing Rails version 3.2.15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i've successfully installed rails 3.2.15 on a live ubuntu usb with data persistence before.

now that i've become used to the os (**Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**), i've installed it on the laptop and in the process of installing the stuff i used back in the live usb.

long story short, i'm having problems with installing Rails. i've used the same instructions to install ruby and rails as the one in the live usb: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

However, i'm getting this error when installing rails:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
>       no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel)

I've used -V to see what's happening but, being a tech noob in general, i dont know whats going wrong.

Here's what -V gave out:

> ~$ gem install rails -V 3.2.15 HEAD
>   https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz 302 Moved Temporarily
>   HEAD
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
>   200 OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz 302 Moved
>   Temporarily GET
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
>   200 OK HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz 302 Moved
>   Temporarily HEAD
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
>   304 Not Modified GET
>   https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.0.2.gemspec.rz 302
>   Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.0.2.gemspec.rz 200
>   OK HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies 302 Moved
>   Temporarily HEAD https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies 200
>   OK HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies 302 Moved
>   Temporarily HEAD https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies 200
>   OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails 302
>   Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails 200 OK GET
>   https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails 302 Moved
>   Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails 200 OK GET
>   https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties 302 Moved
>   Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties 200 OK
>   GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties 302
>   Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=railties 200 OK
>   GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer 302
>   Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer 200
>   OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer
>   302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer 200
>   OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord
>   302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord 200
>   OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord
>   302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activerecord 200
>   OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack
>   302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack 200
>   OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack
>   302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack 200
>   OK GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport
>   302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport
>   200 OK GET
>   https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport 302
>   Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activesupport
>   200 OK GET
>   https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel 302
>   Moved Temporarily GET
>   https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel 200
>   OK ERROR:  While executing gem ...
>   (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
>       no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=activemodel)

anyone can help?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

using:

ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]

rvm 1.25.15 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

probably got the error because internet at home was quite intermittent. When i used the internet connection at work, the install went well.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem: Ubuntu 12.04, ruby 2.1.0 trying to install latest rails (4.0.x).  Doing **gem install rails** I was getting same error.  What I did:

- update rubygem: **gem update --system** and it went from 2.2.0 to 2.2.2
- located outdated gems (**gem outdated**) and got several outdated: bigdecimal (1.2.3 < 1.2.5), minitest (4.7.5 < 5.2.3), psych (2.0.2 < 2.0.4), rake (10.1.0 < 10.1.1), rdoc (4.1.0 < 4.1.1), test-unit (2.1.0.0 < 2.5.5)
- updated gems with **gem update**
- Sucessfully installed rails with  **gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc**

At **rails -v** I got Rails 4.0.3.

Comment: i think the error I received was because I was using an internet connection that was quite intermittent. When i went back to work, the install went fine.

Comment: If the project is managed by bundler, also check https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler