# Getting a fetch error when creating my first web application in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have decided to learn through Derek Banas video tutorial on Rails, so i followed the instructions and downloaded the bundled installer in http://railsinstaller.org/en

Rather than following Derek's walkthrough on web app creation with mysql, i decided to use the bundled sqlite with the syntax

```
rails new sample -d sqlite3
```

but i got this error

http://i.imgur.com/GsL8SVi.png?1

may i know what exactly what i am doing wrong? thanks for the replies!

Comment: What happens when you run `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'`?

Comment: it says something like unable to download data from rubygems.org http://imgur.com/0KjEJnT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're first time use Rails Installer for windows, the OpenSSL library of rails installer delivers has no certificate authorities defined, so you got that problem.

Try this :

1. download this file https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fnichol/867550/raw/win_fetch_cacerts.rb and store any directory (ex : `c:\win_fetch_cacerts.rb`)
2. Open CMD, and run ruby script

   ```
   ruby "c:\win_fetch_cacerts.rb"
   ```
3. Set `SSL_CERT_FILE` to your Environment Variables, open CMD and type and run :

   ```
   set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
   ```
4. Restart your device.

Comment: could i have some clarification at step 3? so i should open cmd and simply input the following command?

Comment: Have you tried it? if you're unsure, try with manual set envireonment variables, right click on computer icon > properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > new system variable.. take a look this screenshoot http://i.stack.imgur.com/PaosO.png

Comment: thanks for the help, I am still not sure why i am getting an error, i followed step 3 and your recommendation but this is happening http://i.imgur.com/z1hiN2h.png

Comment: Your first problem and your current problem are differents, first problem about SSL certificate verify failed have solve with above solution, and your current problem because your internet connection, take a look this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21364283/1297435, The OP have same a problem with your, and an issue is with internet connection.

Comment: thanks for the input, i am using wifi and i switch to utp, i think it's working correctly now http://i.imgur.com/BH5ETY0.png?1

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but you can change the first line of your `Gemfile` to use unsecure connection `source 'http://rubygems.org'` and run `bundle install` manually.